# jcycle prev/next

Tags: jquery, jcycle

So I'm using the jcycle plugin and I've got the pager working the way I want. I've also got the prev/next implemented and that's working, but what I need for those to do is to change the active state of the pager items. So if I click on the next arrow, the "on" state of the pager needs to match the current slide and the same idea with the prev button. Unfortunately I can't share a link. I hope my dilemma makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us some code? Could you make reproducable example on jsfiddle.net? What you currently have doesn't help in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Does this example help? In my experience once you've defined pager elements with jcycle it adds an "activeSlide" class: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html

Update:

Based on your comment, it seems like you're trying to do this: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager11.html

Comment: not really. but i can use that as an example. so you see that it has the pager elements. now imagine that there are prev/next buttons. let's say you click on the next arrow, the active state on the pager should match the slide that is shown. same with the previous button. if you click on the previous button, the active state of the pager should match the slide shown. does that help any at all to what i'm needing?